# Ajax -> storing JS array in mySQl table via php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

[image]I am currently trying to pass an array through AJAX to php and then store it in a table.

**The php file** *(which is running on wamp server)*

```
    <?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "xx";
$dbname = "xx";

$myArray = $_POST['myArr'];

echo $myArray;


$con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password ,$dbname) or die ("could not connect database");

$query = "INSERT INTO inventory_db (timestamp, deviceid, product_name, tray, latitude, longitude, product) VALUES" . $myArray;
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

$con->close();

?>
```

**The Ajax**

```
    function jsonconversion(){

        jsonString = JSON.stringify(myArr);

        $.ajax({        
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://xx.xx.xx.xx:80/xx/sendData.php",
       data: {myData:myArr},
       complete: function() {
            console.log("Success");
       },
       error: function() {
           console.log("Function: forward_to_server() error")
       }
    }); 
}
```

initially I was trying with JSON but I dont't see the need for it now...(should I?)

Comment: That query wont work

Comment: Like I said on last question `url: "xx/sendData.php"` or this wont work when you move it to a live server with a different url

Comment: I don't know why the manual is littered with these calls to die. Instead the manual should be littered with echo, print or other debugging statements. Just echo out your query and you will see why

Comment: Riggs, could you please explain that more, the xx/sendData.php...

Comment: How does phonegap app recognize to send it to wampserver without knowing the ip? I'm quite new to all this sorry about newbness, another thing, how can I debug the sendData.php(which relies on the array coming from the Javascript/phonegap)

Comment: The browser nows which domain its talking to. So all you need to specify is the location within the domain where the script lives

Comment: Oh and by the way `JSON.stringify()` is creating a JSONString so you are still passing a JSON data String from the js to the PHP

Comment: I don't use the jsonString in passing, only the original myArr

Comment: You need to extract the values from `$_POST` and place them in the query one param per column mentioned in the INSERT column list

Comment: Judging by the XDEBUG Errors you are trying to run the javascript function in PHP. **That cant work**. Sorry, but it looks to me like you are in a fairly serious mess here.

Comment: Riggs, the JS script will not live in the same domain, that is why I need to specify the server IP no? When I move it from Wamp to the final server I will need to repalce the IP with the Servers Private IP? So that the app can always know where to send it

Comment: Yes it can't work Riggs, I'm posting the pic to find out, since the PHP relies on the Javascript to work, the Javascript is not on the same server, how can I debug the PHP without relying on the JS.

Comment: Or do as I suggest and you wont have to change anything as long as you keep the basic folder structure the same

Comment: They are NOT in the same folders? And will not know of each others folder structure

Comment: I actually tried it there, remove the IP. It didnt' work

Comment: Sorry to say this Brian, but you seem to be trying to run the marathon before you have learned to crawl. You really need to get a grasp of the basic concepts before you attempt a phonegap app. I would suggest hitting some books and tutorials before you attempt to go any further

Comment: About last night, that worked fine(And removing the ip address from the Ajax call STOPPED IT from working). This is just about passing an Array and making it usable in php. The basic concepts etc...whatever you told me last night(remove return jsonString), worked fine. Now i'm just passing the array in and wondering how to store and use that Array in PHP. None of the other stuff.

Comment: The other question did not need to pass anything for the php to run. This question needs that array now. The URL etc...does it even matter if its working with otr without the ip? So long as its working. the wamp server is live btw

Comment: Thanks for your help anyways Riggs, I will figure it out

Answer (score 0):

Couple of Typo errors :

$myArray = $_POST['myData'];

$fulldata = json_decode($myArray);

print_r($fulldata);
//From Full data, yo need to get these variables mentioned below.

$query = "INSERT INTO inventory_db (timestamp, deviceid, product_name, tray, latitude, longitude, product) VALUES (NOW(), '$deviceid','$product_name', '$myArray', '$try', '$lat','$long', '$prod');

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out anyway. for future reference for fellow phonegap and wamp server users:

```
    $con = mysqli_connect($servername,$username,$password ,$dbname) or die ("could not connect database");

//jsArray is waiting for the Ajax in the android app JS file.
//myArray is placing the JSON object into an array for php to store its values
$jsArray = $_POST['jsonString'];
$myArray = json_decode($jsArray,true);

//the next line is to test and see what happens with an array
//$myArray = array('timestamp' => 1, 'deviceid' => "x1x1x1x1x1x1x1x1x1x1", 'product_name' => "cola", 'tray' => "large", 'latitude' => 5, 'longitude' => 6, 'product_weight'=>7);

//declare variables and use 'key' value in array to input values.
$timestamp = $myArray['timestamp'];
$deviceid = $myArray['deviceid'];
$product_name = $myArray['product1'];
$tray = $myArray['tray'];
$latitude = $myArray['latitude'];
$longitude = $myArray['longitude'];
$product_weight = $myArray['product2'];

//insert into table inventory_db 
$query = "INSERT INTO inventory_db (timestamp, deviceid, product1, tray, latitude, longitude, product2) 
VALUES('$timestamp','$deviceid','$product1','$tray','$latitude','$longitude','$product2')";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));

$con->close();

?>
```

In the JS file, instead of an array I changed it to an Object

```
var myArr = {timestamp:0,deviceid:0,product1:"",type:"",latitude:0,longitude:0, product2:0};
```

Then

```
var jsonString = "";
function jsonconversion(){

        jsonString = JSON.stringify(myArr);
        //console.log(jsonString);

        $.ajax({        
       type: "POST",
       url: "http://x.x.x.x:80/x/sendData.php",
       data: {data:jsonString},
       complete: function() {
            console.log("Success");
       },
       error: function() {
           console.log("Function: forward_to_server() error")
       }
    }); 
}
```

For briggs answer to removing the IP, it still is not working for me if I remove the Ip and leave it in a file structure(Although this does work if i'm using WAMP only with JS/PHP/AJAX)